# $H_{n-1}$ of an orientable n-manifold is free.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I need the statement "$H_{n-1}$ of an orientable manifold is free."(for a seminartalk im given [its more of a little remark but if someone wants me to elaborate i'd be troubled])

I know that it follows from the universal coefficient theorem, but the UVCT is just coming up in my lecture and I am not familiar enough with it to really see how to proof it (its probably really easy).

I would be really happy if someone could explain it to me in "detail".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $M$ be a closed, connected, orientable $n$-manifold. Suppose $H_{n-1}(M)$ has torsion and so for some prime $p$ we have that $\text{Tor}(H_{n-1}(M),\Bbb Z_p)$ is nontrivial. By the UCT we have
\begin{align*}
H_n(M;\Bbb Z_p)&=(H_n(M)\otimes\Bbb Z_p)\oplus\text{Tor}(H_{n-1}(M),\Bbb Z_p)\\
&=\Bbb Z_p\oplus \text{Tor}(H_{n-1}(M),\Bbb Z_p).
\end{align*}
However, we know that $H_n(M)=\Bbb Z$ and so $H_n(M;\Bbb Z_p)=\Bbb Z_p$. But this is a contradiction since $\Bbb Z_p\neq\Bbb Z_p\oplus\text{Tor}(H_{n-1}(M),\Bbb Z_p)$.